# how to get real measurements of two points from a 360 image in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

how to get a real measure of two points in a 360 picture of an interior using a-frame.io framework?

we tried converting the unit system of a-frame to centimeter and took two points where the dimensions were known and set it as default. and estimated that any other points we take would be relatively correct but it isn't.

any other suggestions or formula that could help?

thank you

Comment: I have no idea how `a-frame` works, so ignore this comment if the question is something really framework-specific. Could you clarify what you mean by "distance"? I mean is it distance on screen between 2 points, distance in virtual 3D view or something else? The reason I ask is: In 3d space distance between 2 points is a straight line, but when 3d view (which would have a slight curvature) expressed on a flat surface the line should be slightly longer (similar to how path an arm travels when rotating it is longer than distance between end points )

Answer (score 1):

That can't work. At least unless you have a depth-image as well. What you can easily get from a single 360° image are two angles for pan and tilt. If you add a third value, the distance from the camera (also called depth), you have so called spherical coordinates which can be converted to cartesian coordinates (x, y, z).

Without knowing that distance you can only reconstruct a ray, but not a single point. You need one more piece of information to determine where along that ray the point is (which is what you need to know for any measurements in the image).